# Proofs using theory of differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

There are unique functions $,:ℝ→ℝ$ such that

- ${}\,'()=()$ for all $∈ℝ$;
- ${}\,'()=−()$ for all $∈ℝ$;
- $(0)=0;$
- $(0)=1.$

$(())^2+(())^2=1$

**For $c ∈ \mathbb{R}$ I will have to show**

- $(f(x+c))^2 + (g(x+c))^2 = 1$
- $(f(c)g(x) + g(c)f(x))^2 + (g(c)g(x) − f(c)f(x))^2 = 1$

Part 2:

Let, 
\begin{align}
w_1(x) &= f(x+c), 
\\
w_2(x) &= g(x+c), 
\\
w_3(x) &= f(c)g(x)+g(c)f(x) ~~\text{ and }
\\
w_4(x) &= g(c)g(x) − f(c)f(x)
\end{align}
Then, 
\begin{align}
w_1'(x) &= w_2(x), 
\\
w_2'(x) &= −w_1(x)
\\
w_3'(x) &=  w_4(x)
\\
w_4'(x) &= −w_3(x)
\\
q(x) &= w_1(x)w_4(x) − w_2(x)w_3(x)
\end{align}

**I will have to show: For every $x∈\mathbb{R},\ q(x)=0$**

My solutions:

$$(f(x+c))^2 + (g(x+c))^2 = 1$$ follows directly from the fact that $(())^2+(())^2=1$

\begin{align}
&(f(c)g(x) + g(c)f(x))^2 + (g(c)g(x) − f(c)f (x))^2
\\[.5em]
&= (f(c))^2(g(x))^2 + (g(c))^2(f(x))^2 + 2f(c)g(x)g(c)f(x) 
\\&\qquad+(g(c))^2(g(x))^2 + (f(c))^2(f(x))^2 − 2g(c)g(x)f(c)f(x)
\\[.5em]
&= g(x))^2 [(f(c))^2 + (g(c))^2]+ (f(x))^2[(g(c))^2 + (f(c))^2]
\\[.5em]
&= [(g(x))^2 +(f(x))^2] [(f(c))^2 + (g(c))^2]
\\
&= 1
\end{align}

Am I on the right track?

For second part:

using Leibniz rule I can show $q'(x)= 0$.

I am quite not sure how to show $q(x) = 0$

Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is all looking very complicated. Why not just show that $f(x)f(x+c)+g(x)g(x+c)=g(c)$ and $g(x)f(x+c)-f(x)g(x+c)=f(c)$ are constants of the ODE system? All the other identities should follow from these.

Comment: Please format equations using MathJax.